# Failure starting repl - Databricks Runtime 10.2

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am currently using Databricks Runtime Version 10.2.

Spark 3.2.0
Scala 2.12

My databricks environment is connected to Azure datafactory and some ETL processes are controlled by ADF, which calls come notebooks.

During some nightly executions yesterday, some notebooks execution failed due to a Python REPL Fail. All the commands using SQL were executed with success. In the LOG4J, we can find this information:

```
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO ClusterLoadAvgHelper: Current cluster load: 0, Old Ema: 1.0, New Ema: 0.85 
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO DriverCorral$: Cleaning the wrapper ReplId-24857-1b125-4a48b-2 (currently in status Idle(ReplId-24857-1b125-4a48b-2))
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO DriverCorral$: sending shutdown signal for REPL ReplId-24857-1b125-4a48b-2
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO PythonDriverLocal$Watchdog: Python shell exit code: 143
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO PythonDriverLocal$RedirectThread: Python RedirectThread exit
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO PythonDriverLocal$RedirectThread: Python RedirectThread exit
22/06/06 08:29:57 INFO PythonDriverLocal$Watchdog: Recovered content from strace: 08:29:30.225363 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_20, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225418 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_21, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225477 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_22, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225537 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_23, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225585 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_24, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225643 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_25, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225693 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_26, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225751 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_27, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225810 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_28, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225882 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_29, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.225949 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.226001 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_31, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.226052 rt_sigaction(SIGRT_32, NULL, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:30.976436 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=22555, si_uid=1008, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
08:29:33.137970 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x1579b5, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f264b542451}, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0
08:29:33.422342 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=22601, si_uid=1008, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
08:29:33.435246 --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=22605, si_uid=1008, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
08:29:35.153144 rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {sa_handler=0x1579b5, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f264b542451}, {sa_handler=0x1579b5, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER, sa_restorer=0x7f264b542451}, 8) = 0
08:29:57.588474 --- SIGTERM {si_signo=SIGTERM, si_code=SI_USER, si_pid=225, si_uid=0} ---
08:29:57.593757 +++ killed by SIGTERM +++
22/06/05 08:29:57 INFO PythonDriverLocal$Watchdog: Processes currently running in the container:
==========
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:41 systemd
   48 ?        00:00:01 systemd-journal
   89 ?        00:00:00 networkd-dispat
   90 ?        00:00:02 systemd-logind
   91 ?        00:00:00 sshd
  100 ?        00:00:00 ntpd
  107 ?        00:00:00 monit
  112 ?        00:00:00 unattended-upgr
  155 ?        00:00:00 start_wsfs.sh
  181 ?        00:00:02 goofys-dbr
  187 ?        00:00:00 wsfs
  312 ?        00:04:32 java
  466 ?        00:00:11 java
  512 ?        00:00:00 apache2
  517 ?        00:00:00 cron
  601 ?        00:00:00 bash
  225 ?        00:41:12 java
 1028 ?        00:00:02 strace
 1140 ?        00:00:02 strace
 1170 ?        00:00:02 strace
 1321 ?        00:00:00 bash
 1368 ?        00:00:00 R
22511 ?        00:00:00 check_dbfs_fuse <defunct>
22799 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

The cluster memory when the error happened was aprox 75%. CPU and network use also had 80% use peaks some seconds before the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ub70W.png)